# PROBLEMA CON CODIGO &#65279; EN MI HTML

Tags: php, html, css, utf-8

Después de un buen tiempo de trabajo con mi página he notado que aparece un salto de linea en la cabecera de mi página web, y el footer se alarga más de la cuenta. 
el codigo que muestra en el panel es **"#65279;"** a lo cual he realizado una exaustiva busqueda y veo que el resultado tiene que ver con una codificación **BOM** para caracteres especiales, y la solución que ofrecen es usar la herramienta de guardar en UTF-8 sin BOM . a lo cual no me ha surgido efecto, alguien podría tener otra solución o razón por la cual esto es causado?

Comment: Hola amigo. Si pudieras editar tu pregunta agregando el código de tu pagina, de tu css, una imagen de como se ve tu pagina y otra indicando como se espera es muy probable que alguien se anime a ayudarte.

Comment: Me seria complicado añadir el código ya que bastante extenso por el lado del css y el de mi pagina es implementado con modelo vista controlador. Como debería verse es como se ve una pagina web normalmente, como se ve ahora es con un salto de linea antes de la barra de navegación un espaciado blanco y un footer alargado. En estos momentos no me seria posible hacer una captura de la vista pero en cuanto me sea posible lo haré, creo que el problema no es muy difícil de entender si buscas ese código en internet, lo difícil es corregirlo

Comment: @AlvaroC El carácter es considerado invisible ya que es considerado como un salto de linea, a lo que causa ese problema, lo complicado es que este carácter en el código tampoco se ve.

Comment: puedes solucionar el error con el Notepad++ es gratuito, te permitirá editar tu código de manera fácil y podrás solucionar tu problema. Una vez instales el editor, simplemente ves al menú codifcación y selecciona  Codificar en UTF-8 sin BOM y vuelve a guardar y subir el archivo a tu ftp. A mi también me pasaba, sbre todo con archivos XML.

Comment: @Dismark si, eso ya lo intenté pero no surgió efecrto. seleccione la opción de Decoding, y Re Decode With UTF-8 . que es lo equivalente a codigicar sin BOM, pero la vista sigue con el mismo problema.

Comment: esa sería la única posible razón por la que este error se muestre? 
Otra cosa a mencionar es se imprimen algunas vistas por medio de los controladores, el error podría alojarse ahí también?

Comment: El error podría estar en cualquier archivo que hayas editado. Yo en tu caso lo que haría es depurar. Seleccionar una vista donde tienes el problema, ver que archivos intervienen y abrirlos todos con el Notepad++. Seleccionas la opción de  Codificar en UTF-8 sin BOM y has una barra espaciadora o cualquier otro cambio, después eliminalo, eso hará que puedas guardar el archivo con ese cambio, que en realidad no lo fué y ese archivo concreto se guardará sin BOM. Haz lo mismo con los que intervienen en esa vista ( controlador, vista y modelo)  y vuelve a subir al ftp  y prueba de nuevo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO **SUBLIME TEXT** POSEE UNA CARACTERÍSTICA SIMILAR DENTRO DE LA OPCIÓN "FILE" -> SAVE WITH ENCODING -> UTF-8 FUE NECESARIO REALIZAR LA ACCIÓN EN TODAS LAS VISTAS Y CONTROLADORES QUE IMPRIMEN HTML.

Comment: Edita la respuesta escribiendo con un mejor formato, mayúsculas == gritar. Gracias :D

Comment: Excelente!, tenia el mismo problema y esto lo soluciono